# How to get values in a tableview cell

Tags: iphone

I have a tableview cells containing bible verses one by one in each cell,my need is when the user tap the cell i have to get the verse inside the tapped cell in a string formate.this is for sharing functionality.
Please help me.

Comment: How do you create cell and put there verses?

Comment: I guess using an array u do that rite ?

Comment: @booleanBoy i am using array for storing verses.

Comment: @Nekto from sqldatabase i store it as a array .the verses are already in tableview cell.but my need is when the user tap it it will have to store as a string and used for sharing function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the verse, you likely used

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

To get the verse back from a tapped cell, you use

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

When filling the tableView, you used `indexPath` to get the right verse - thats what you want to do now again. Assuming you have a `NSArray` called 'verses':

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSString *verse = [verses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSLog(@"The selected verse is: %@",verse);
}
```

Comment: but there is more than 3000 verses ,how to write code for this .?

Comment: the same way you filled the cells with verses. I guess you have an `NSArray` of verses, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

If verse is already in a standard UITableViewCell, you can access it via UITableViewCell property, like cell.textLabel.text or cell.detailTextLabel.text. Examine UITableViewCell class reference.

Answer (score 0):

use the same array to get the string....
In didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate

have a code like this

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@",[yourArray ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

You can also use the above code to get the string in a NSString variable.